# Find a string list whether containing same element more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, list, element, contains

I am writing my own specific web crawler for product selling websites. Due to their very bad coding nature i get with getting urls pointing same page.

Example one

```
http://www.hizlial.com/bilgisayar/bilgisayar-bilesenleri/bilgisayar/yazicilar/samsung-scx-3200-tarayici-fotokopi-lazer-yazici_30.033.1271.0043.htm
```

For example the page above is same as below

```
http://www.hizlial.com/bilgisayar-bilesenleri/bilgisayar/yazicilar/samsung-scx-3200-tarayici-fotokopi-lazer-yazici_30.033.1271.0043.htm
```

As you can see it contains 2 "bilgisayar" element when you split via `'/'` character

So what i want is i want to split urls like this

```
 string[] lstSPlit = srURL.Split('/');
```

After that check that whether that list contains same element more than once or not. Any element. If contains any element i will skip the url because i would have already have the real url extracted from some other page. So what is the best way of doing this ?

Longer but working version

```
string[] lstSPlit = srHref.Split('/');
bool blDoNotAdd = false;
HashSet<string> splitHashSet=new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var vrLstValue in lstSPlit)
{
    if (vrLstValue.Length > 1)
    {
        if (splitHashSet.Contains(vrLstValue) == false)
        {
            splitHashSet.Add(vrLstValue);
        }
        else
        {
            blDoNotAdd = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to check whether `lstSPlit` contains the same item more than once? Or do you want to check whether it contains items that you've seen in previous runs?

Comment: same item more than once. it can be any item it has

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (list.Distinct().Count() < list.Count)
```

This ought to be faster than grouping.  (I haven't measured)

You can make it even faster by writing your own extension method that adds items to a `HashSet<T>` and returns false immediately if `Add()` returns false.

You can even do that using a wicked shorthand:

```
if (!list.All(new HashSet<string>().Add))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. working great. corrected version  "if (lstSPlit.Distinct().Count() < lstSPlit.Length)"

Comment: Hello. Very important another issue. I also need to add length restriction. For example when this is given as url : http://www.exa.com.tr/ it gets 2 empty string and causes me to skip it. So i have to say that the element length bigger than 2 for example

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Just put a `Where` on both sides.  The hashset version will then be even more efficient.

Comment: I added longer and working version. Can you check and comment on it. Added to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: You can replace the whole inner `if`/`else` block with `if(!splitHashSet.Add(vrLstValue)) { ... break; }`

Comment: You can replace the outer `if` block with a `Where` in the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(lstSPlit.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Any())
{
    // found more than once
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose SLaks method would work faster :)